# inserting numeric results of a function into perl array using a for loop

Tags: arrays, perl

i am new to perl and i want to do something similar to what i do in C.

```
for(i=0;i<32;i++)
{
array[i]= some_function_result();
}
and then print the array
```

and for doing this, what i am trying to do in perl is

```
@data=();
for($i=0;$i<32;$i++){   
    $hexval = unpack('H2',substr($payload,$i,1));
        @data[$i]=$hexval;
}
print @data;
```

is this correct?
i tried to use the functions like push(@data,$hexval) but that resulted in

> 32
>
> 64
>
> 96...

i know this is naive..but can someone help me out with this please..

Comment: Do you have `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your script? This would spot that you should use `$data[$i]` instead of `@data[$i]` for instance.

Comment: if i do that, it gives me this

Global symbol "@data" requires explicit package name at arraystest.pl line 18.
Global symbol "$ip" requires explicit package name at arraystest.pl line 23.
Global symbol "$tcp" requires explicit package name at arraystest.pl line 24.
Global symbol "$ip" requires explicit package name at arraystest.pl line 24.
Global symbol "$payload" requires explicit package name at arraystest.pl line 25.
Global symbol "$tcp" requires explicit package name at arraystest.pl line 25.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<32; i++) {
   array[i]= some_function_result();
}
```

is

```
for (my $i=0; $i<32; $i++) {
   $array[$i] = some_function_result();
}
```

or better yet

```
for my $i (0..31) {
   $array[$i] = some_function_result();
}
```

Flow control statements are documented in [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html).

Variable types are documented in [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).

(Accessible using `perldoc perlsyn` or even `man perlsyn`.)

You should indeed always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: nope.. even if i use that, all i get is 32 in my array.. nothing other than that..

Comment: I assure you those two snippets are equivalent. And I assure you are mistaken about only getting "32" in your array. You'll get 32 values of some sort (even if undef) as returned by `some_function_result`.

Comment: the way am printing it is print @data;
is that the right way to do?

Comment: Well, the array is named `@array`, not `@data`. Other than that, it depends what output you want. That will print the elements of the array `@data`.

Comment: i want the complete array to be printed.. i.e., all the elements present in the array.. or all the elements that are added to the array

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29780/discussion-between-ikegami-and-kiran-vemuri)